# When is a Talmudic statement considerd aggadah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, agada-stories-legends, talmudic-methodology

When is a statement in the Talmud considerd aggadah (and thus [not necessarily to be taken litteraly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/does-one-have-to-take-a-midrash-aggadah-literally), but rather teaches us a lesson) and when is a statement in the Talmud acctually literal? (i.e that it actually happened).

For example: the talmud in [Yevamoth 60b:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.60b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) states a [seemingly immoral story](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96563/when-is-it-moral-to-line-up-and-kill-thousands-of-little-girls-a-question-on-th), can this statement be considerd aggadah or did it acctually happen? And also for example the story of Abraham's ten tests, this is certainly taken litteraly but how do we differentiate?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37652/how-do-different-scholars-define-aggadah

Comment: ...if it appears in עין יעקב?

Comment: Any rule you find will have exceptions.

Comment: When I see a story in the sources, I assume it's either factual (conveys information), with or without a lesson; or it's a parable invented to teach a lesson.  If I don't see or hear of a lesson, I assume it's factual.

Comment: This question asks about Gemara, but then continues by bringing incidents that are pretty much explicit in the Written Torah.

Answer (score 2):

To narrowly answer your question: Halacha teaches laws, and Aggada is everything else. The Aggada of the Talmud is collected in the work Ein Yaakov. The author/compiler explains in his introduction that Rabbi Yitzchak Al Fasi had already collected the Halacha into one work. This division is only used in Rabbinic works, not the Bible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if the statement in Yevamoth 60b:11 is aggadah?

Comment: The part about using the tzitz is Aggadah. The killing of the Midianites is historic, and mentioned in Tanach. The understanding of the age of the girls is halachic, as it teaches that a convert under three can marry a kohen.